# Write data from stored proc to .dbf file, c#

Tags: c#, sql

How i can select data from stored proc and insert them to file.dbf, using c#?
Some code that i have:

```
OleDbConnection lDbfConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        try
        {
            lDbfConnection.Open();

            OleDbParameter lScript = new OleDbParameter(
                "script",
                 @"create table Result (colums parameters)
                 OleDbCommand lOleDbCommand = lDbfConnection.CreateCommand();
                 lOleDbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                 lOleDbCommand.CommandText = "ExecScript";
                 lOleDbCommand.Parameters.Add(lScript);
                 lOleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 lOleDbCommand = lDbfConnection.CreateCommand();
                 lOleDbCommand.CommandText = "insert into Result(colums)
```

//code that i need

```
                  SqlConnection lProcConnection = new SqlConnection(lConnect);
                  SqlCommand lCommand = new SqlCommand(lProcName, lProcConnection);
                  lCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                  //input parameters
                  lCommand.Parameters.Add("ParamName", SqlDbType.Type).Value =SomeValue; 
                  lProcConnection.Open();
                  ......
```

Comment: You seem to think that somehow maticlally an OlDb parameter can execute C# script. No, it will not. It also will not make you coffee. YOu have to stick to SQL here, and no, it can not write to a DBF file.

Comment: Need to add some intermediary table I think, but i don't know where, and how to write data from proc to that table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [VfpClient](http://vfpclient.codeplex.com) to help you.

Here is an example:

```
using(var connection = new SqlConnection("connectionString")) {
    using(var command = connection.CreateCommand()) {
        command.CommandText = "storedProcedure";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        var data = new DataTable("TableName");

        // This will execute the stored procedure and put the data in a data table.
        var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        adapter.Fill(data);

        // This will create a dbc.
        var dbc = @"c:\Data\Data.dbc";
        var dbcCreator = new VfpClient.Utils.DbcCreator.DataTableDbcCreator(dbc);

        // This will create a dbf with the data retrieved from the stored procedure.
        dbcCreator.Add(data);
    }
}
```